# Create Route from XML in Camel 4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

In preparation of the release of Camel 4.0 i am trying to find a way to migrate my methods which create `Route` or `RouteDefinition` objects from a XML file with routes written like:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
                            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.20.2.xsd">


    <route id=....>
......
    </route>
</routes>
```

so they can be loaded into CamelContext

In Camel 3.20 i was loading them into the CamelContext like

```
            String xmlContent = myBean.getXMLFileContent();//imagine this string's content is as described above
//I am open to converting this string into a java.io.File and new methodologies that the Camel team is leaning towards
            try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes())) {

                XMLRoutesDefinitionLoader loader =   extendedCamelContext.getXMLRoutesDefinitionLoader();
                RoutesDefinition routesDefinition = (RoutesDefinition) loader.loadRoutesDefinition(camelContext, is);
                modelCamelContext.addRouteDefinitions(routesDefinition.getRoutes());
            }
```

by importing

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-xml-io</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The class used here does not exist any more in camel 4.0 https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.21.0/org/apache/camel/spi/XMLRoutesDefinitionLoader.html. Question is how to load XML Routes without this class?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me it got solved by adding the entire spring boot start dependency. Seems like some classes changed.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-xml-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Can you give this a try?